# Start applications via remote control

Tags: remote-control

I am searching for a way to start multiple, pre-defined applications via apple's remote control. Is this at all possible with Mavericks?

I have a special user account on my iMac that is used for watching films via Plex and DVB-T via EyeTv. While I can close all these applications via remote-control as soon as they are running, I have not found a way to start them.

Is there a third-party app that allows such a functionality? I already tried [RemoteBuddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/) but it was much too complex for my needs.

Comment: Please add to your original question a specific example of your need, so as to get practical answers.
Typo: to complex → too complex ☺.

Comment: My bad, sorry. I have added a more detailed usage example to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/) supports remapping Apple's remote controllers and you can run a shell script (like `open -a Preview;open -a TextEdit`) to open multiple applications.

[image]

Comment: An impressive tool, thanks. Unfortunately there seem to be some problems with other apps not receiving the input from the remote-control ([related](https://forums.plexapp.com/index.php/topic/30587-making-plex-and-bettertouchtool-work-together/)).